# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' when trying to remove character

Tags: python, xml, string, list, xpath

I am trying to remove the character ' from my string by doing the following

```
kickoff = tree.xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div[1]/div/main/div/article/div/div[1]/section[2]/p[1]/b[1]/text()')
kickoff = kickoff.replace("'", "")
```

This gives me the error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'

Coming from a php background I am unsure what the correct way to do this is?

Comment: You have a list, not a string. I haven't tested this but try `kickoff = [k.replace("'", "") for k in kickoff]`

Comment: Replace only works on strings

Answer (score 31):

[`xpath`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#xpath) method returns a list, you need to iterate items.

```
kickoff = [item.replace("'", "") for item in kickoff]
```

Comment: Thanks - this is whats confused me ... little bit different to php in the sense :)

Comment: @emmaperkins, `list`'s methods are different from `str`'s methods.

Answer (score 7):

```
kickoff = tree.xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div[1]/div/main/div/article/div/div[1]/section[2]/p[1]/b[1]/text()')
```

This code is returning list not a string.Replace function will not work on list.

```
[i.replace("'", "") for i in kickoff ]
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
kickoff = str(tree.xpath('//*[@id="page"]/div[1]/div/main/div/article/div/div[1]/section[2]/p[1]/b[1]/text()'))
kickoff = kickoff.replace("'", "")
```

This error is caused because the xpath returns in a list. Lists don't have the replace attribute. So by putting str before it, you convert it to a string which the code can handle. I hope this helped!