# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace' Python

Tags: python

What am I missing in the below? I keep getting error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

I've followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36642782/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-replace-when-trying-to-remove-c) and elsewhere but something is still not working.

```
import json
import requests

search_terms = input('Name of university: ')
parameters = {"affiliation": search_terms}
response = requests.get("https://api.ror.org/organizations", params=parameters)

ror_payload = response.json()

name_variations_provisional = []
for organisation in ror_payload['items']:
    if organisation['chosen']==True:
        name_variations_provisional.append(organisation['organization']['name'])
        name_variations_provisional.append(organisation['organization']['aliases'])
        for relationship in organisation['organization']['relationships']:
            if relationship['type'] == 'Child':
               name_variations_provisional.append(relationship['label'])

#this is the line that's not working
name_variations=[str.replace("C", "") for str in name_variations_provisional]

print(name_variations)
```

Comment: please don't name local variables after builtin types like str and list. that's bad practice by itself - made worse here because variable `str` appears to be a list.

Comment: My suspicion though, is it is the line where you append the value of the `aliases` key to `name_variations_provisional`. Since "aliases" is plural, I would assume it's a list of some type, rather than a string as is assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`organisation['organization']['aliases']` is probably a list. Use `extend()` rather than `append()` so that each element is appended separately, rather than the whole list being appended as a single element.

```
name_variations_provisional.extend(organisation['organization']['aliases'])
```